# C++ linkage error for inline member function

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

*IFile.h*

```
class IFile
{
public:
    IFile();
    ~IFile(void);

    inline bool IsValidFileType() const;
};
```

*IFile.cpp*

```
IFile::IFile()
{
    //IsValidFileType();
}

IFile::~IFile(void)
{
}

inline bool IFile::IsValidFileType() const
{
          return true;
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IFile* pFile = new IFile();
    pFile->IsValidFileType();

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling the code I get the following error:
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall IFile::IsValidFileType(void)const " (?IsValidFileType@IFile@@QBE_NXZ) referenced in function _main

If I change wither "inline" or "const" qualiferes for the function, or call it inside the constructor, the program will complile.
Can you please explain this behaviour?

Comment: For it to be inlined, it needs to be visible at the call location. Putting it in the header would be one way to fix it

Comment: "inline" doesn't mean "not in line" :-(

Comment: Please search before asking. There are so many duplicates for this....

Answer (score 0):

How can the compiler inline a function whose code it cannot see while it is compiling? When compiling `main.cpp`, the compiler is being asked to do just this.

Answer (score 0):

An inline function's code gets compiled into each translation unit that references it (that's the idea, after all). Meaning, you need to include the code in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

The `inline` keyword promises to the compiler that it will be able to see the definition in each translation unit (*.cpp file) in which it is used.  You break this promise, since main.cpp can't see the definition although it includes IFile.h.

Usually functions with the `inline` keyword should be defined in a header file, not a source file.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense, but why removing the const also solves the issue?

Comment: I can't see any reason removing the `const`s and doing nothing else would make a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is inline, you have to define it in the header file, not in the `cpp` file.